# multivariate normal random distribution with OpenCV or pure C#

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, gaussian

I am wondering if a function that preform multivariate normal random distribution exists .. I searched and I found it in OpenCV with C++ .. I want it in C# .. can any body help me out?

thank you all

Comment: System.Random is a decent random generator.

Comment: @MrFox, `System.Random` does not generate Gaussian/normal distributions.  It will only generate uniform distributions.

Comment: For a single dimensional Gaussian distributed random number, look here: http://svn.code.sf.net/p/sharpneat/code/branches/V2/src/SharpNeatLib/Utility/ZigguratGaussianSampler.cs  and go up a level to see a directory that also has the implementation of FastRandom.

Comment: [This question provides several options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9398331/24874)