# multivariate normal distribution given mean vector and covariance matrix

Tags: c#, .net, probability, gaussian

I admit I am being lazy here but is anyone aware of a free math .net library which gives me the output of a normal distribution given a mean vector and a covariance matrix? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Math.NET might work for you.

http://www.mathdotnet.com/

http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/probability-distributions/

> Multivariate Distributions
>
> ```
> Dirichlet
> Inverse Wishart
> Matrix Normal
> Multinomial
> NormalGamma
> Wishart
> ```

Function Reference:

http://api.mathdotnet.com/Numerics/MathNet.Numerics.Distributions/MatrixNormal.htm

EDIT : Note that you have to download from here

http://mathnetnumerics.codeplex.com/releases/view/56448

other links on mathdotnet.com are out of date.

Comment: Thanks. I came accros this earlier. Looking at the source code I cannot find Multinomial - do you know where it is? Thanks.

Comment: http://api.mathdotnet.com/Numerics/MathNet.Numerics.Distributions/Multinomial.htm

Comment: If I understand this correctly it produces a random number given mean vector and covariance matrix. I do not want a random number. I would like the exact output of the multivariate normal distribution. Thanks.

Comment: The MatrixNormal distribution takes a mean matrix plus covariance for rows and columns and generates a random *matrix* whose elements have the appropriate distribution... isn't that what you're after?

Comment: What I would like is one number y. i.e. the output of the multivariate normal distribution given the mean vector and covariance matrix.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're talking about.  Perhaps my maths isn't what it used to be, but as I understand a distribution it is not a single number - it is a property of a set of numbers (discrete distribution) or otherwise is a continuous analytical function.  I dont' think I quite follow what you're looking for.

Comment: sorry I meant: What I would like is one number y - i.e. the output of the multivariate normal distribution given the mean vector, covariance matrix and X - where X is the feature vector/point in the nulti variate feature space. does this make sense now? In other words I want f(X,mean_vector,covariance_matrix) which is just one value!

Comment: ...so you want to generate a probability for a specific point in the feature space, not generate an entire distribution over that space?

Comment: Yes! Some (static) method I can invoke for several such points.

Comment: Well, I updated my answer to include a link to the current distribution of Math.NET - this actually has the new distributions like MatrixNormal - links on their page are out of date.  Anyway, I'm just having a look at it now and I think this can probably do what you want.  MatrixNormal has a function `.Density` (doesn't seem to be documented) which evaluates the probability density for the distribution once you've assigned it mean, covariance.

Answer (score 2):

In the bivariate case, you can express the covariance matrix as a single parameter *rho*.  Here is a method that implements this directly:

```
[Pure]
public static double GetBivariateGuassian(double muX, double sigmaX, double muY, double sigmaY, double x, double y, double rho = 0)
{
    var sigmaXSquared = Math.Pow(sigmaX, 2);
    var sigmaYSquared = Math.Pow(sigmaY, 2);

    var dX = x - muX;
    var dY = y - muY;

    var exponent = -0.5;
    var normaliser = 2 * Math.PI * sigmaX * sigmaY;
    if (rho != 0)
    {
        normaliser *= Math.Sqrt(1 - Math.Pow(rho, 2));
        exponent /= 1 - Math.Pow(rho, 2);
    }

    var sum = Math.Pow(dX, 2)/sigmaXSquared;
    sum += Math.Pow(dY, 2)/sigmaYSquared;
    sum -= 2*rho*dX*dY/(sigmaX*sigmaY);

    exponent *= sum;

    return Math.Exp(exponent) / normaliser;
}
```

See [Bivariate Normal Distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case) on Wikipedia for reference.